# Understanding the beginning and end of word pattern-atoms

Tags: regular-expression

In the [Practical Vim](https://pragprog.com/book/dnvim2/practical-vim-second-edition) book, there is an example of a regular expression that matches duplicate words:

```
/\v<(\w+)\_s+\1>
```

While this works beautifully, I don't quite understand why it also matches the `a a` part in `Once upon a a time.`. I mean, shouldn't the `<` be same as `\W\zs\w` and `>` same as `\w\ze\W`? If yes, then already the beginning of the regex(`/\v\W\zs\w(\w+)...`) should require at least two consecutive word characters because of `\w(\w+)`.

Comment: `\<` and `\>` do *not* use `\zs` and `\ze`! They are [zero-width](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/pattern.html#/zero-width) characters.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`\<` and `\>` are zero-width word boundaries.  They allow you to match the beginning and end of words without moving the cursor that's currently evaluating the character.

The difference between `\W` and `\< \>` is that `\W` is simply `[^0-9A-Za-z_]` whereas `\< \>` are affected by `'iskeyword'` which can be different depending on the `filetype`.  In some files, `hypenated-word` is one word, while in others it's two words separated by a non-word character.

`\zs` and `\ze` are zero-width atoms that *set* the boundaries for capture group `\0`.  They are useful for changing what is considered a match.

For instance, you have a list of words:

```
berry
cherry
ferry
```

You want to replace `erry` in everything below, but not when `h` comes before it.  A substitution like `%s/[^h]erry/xxx/g` would result in:

```
xxx
cherry
xxx
```

It didn't replace `cherry`, but it replaced the character that came before `erry` in the other words.  This is because `[^h]` is still part of the match.

You can use `\zs` to set the beginning of the match for the substitution with `%s/[^h]\zserry/xxx/g`, which will give you:

```
bxxx
cherry
fxxx
```

`\ze` works the same way, but sets where the match ends.

`\zs` and `\ze` are particularly useful with the `search()` and `matchstr()` functions.